# Calling Java Method from within JSNI method

Tags: gwt

I am trying to call a java method from within my JSNI method. I am not getting any type of error but the `Window.alert()` never gets called.

```
package com.mywebsite.myapp.client;

public class MyApp implements EntryPoint(){
/// Other stuff....
    public native void getToServer(String trainerName)/*-{
    $wnd.$.get( "http://testdastuff.dev/trainerstats", { trainer: trainerName} )
     .fail(function() {
        $wnd.console.log("error");
    })
     .done(function( data ) {
          if(data == "noData"){
           alert("NO DATA");
          this.@com.mywebsite.myapp.client.MyApp::testJSNI()();          
    }
    });
    }-*/;


    public void testJSNI(){
        Window.alert("Working");
    }

}
```

It is alerting "NO DATA" so i know something is wrong with the way I am calling the method. It cant be a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the `done` callback you will have lost `this` (it will point to something else now).

You need to preserve it via `bind` or a local variable (`var self = this`).